# How can I delete object with DbContext in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, entity-framework

I have this delete method:

```
private void btnDeleteOrderLine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OrderLine orderLine = (OrderLine)dgvOrderLine.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
    db.OrderLines.Remove(orderLine);
    db.SaveChanges();
    refreshGrid();
}
```

when I click that delete button, I get this error:

> The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the
>   `ObjectStateManager`.

I found out that it is because there were two instances of `Context` class. So, I tried this:

```
private void btnDeleteOrderLine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OrderLine orderLine = (OrderLine)dgvOrderLine.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
    db.OrderLines.Attach(orderLine);  // added this part
    db.OrderLines.Remove(orderLine);
    db.SaveChanges();
    refreshGrid();
}
```

then this gave me the following error:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
>   `IEntityChangeTracker`.

How can I fix this and delete an object from Context DbSet?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have first to find the item from the context and then remove it. I have used a property called `Id`. This is not might be the case. You have to set there the corresponding key property.

```
var selectedOrderLine = (OrderLine)dgvOrderLine.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;

// Here using the context class we try to find if there is the 
// selected item at all 
var orderLine = db.OrderLines.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Id == selectedOrderLine.Id);

if(orderLine!=null)
{
    // The items exists. So we remove it and calling 
    // the db.SaveChanges this will be removed from the database.
    db.OrderLines.Remove(orderLine);
    db.SaveChanges();
    refreshGrid();
}
```

Now let's go a bit deeper, in order we understand the following error message:

> The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the
> ObjectStateManager.

What is the `ObjectStateManager` class? Accoding to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> ObjectStateManager **tracks query results**, and provides logic to merge
> multiple overlapping query results. It also **performs in-memory change**
> **tracking when a user inserts, deletes, or modifies objects, and**
> **provides the change set for updates**. This change set is used by the
> change processor to persist modifications.

In addition to the above:

> This class is typically used by ObjectContext and **not directly** in
> applications.

Comment: Love this :) Thank you sir !

Comment: I would love to see this updated to include the definition of db and item.

Answer (score 1):

Try using delete instead of remove and wrap it in using

```
using (YourContext db = new YourContext())
 {
            db.OrderLines.Attach(orderLine);  // added this part
            db.OrderLines.DeleteObject(orderLine);
            db.SaveChanges();   
  }
```